# Como usar IN no Filter de um ClientDataSet?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

De acordo com a [documentação](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter) da Embarcadero eu posso utilizar `IN` no *Filter* de um *ClientDataSet*, vide exemplo retirado da própria documentação:

`Country IN (SELECT Country from Country where Currency = '_Franc')`

Mas quando dou um `Filtered:= True` no meu *ClientDataSet* com `Filter := id NOT IN (22,43)` recebo o erro:

> Filter expression incorrectly terminated

Pelo erro posso dizer que o problema é o filtro, mas gostaria de entender, se tinha um exemplo na documentação, o que está errado? Qual a forma correta de fazer?

O DataSet conta com 18 registros, possui um *field* com nome 'id' e eu sei que dentre esses 18 registros existem ids diferentes e que se encaixam na condição.

Preciso filtrar o *DataSet*, não posso filtrar a *Query* que uso para preenchê-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era a expressão do filtro, funcionou depois que eu utilizei da seguinte forma:

`Filter := NOT (id IN ( 22 , 43 ) )`

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Diego, existem algumas particularidades conforme o tipo de DataSet, sendo que algumas opções estão disponíveis apenas para alguns Datasets. Se você reparar bem, o trecho que você citou está em exemplos para uma TIBTable.
Acho que para um TClientDataSet, se for um filtro simples como esse que você postou, a alternativa seria utilizar o operador Or mesmo ou utilizar código no evento OnFilterRecord em vez de preencher a propriedade Filter.

Espero que ajude

Comment: Tem razão, não tinha me atentado a esse detalhe, falha minha nessa parte. No entanto, consegui utilizar. O erro estava na forma como eu estava fazendo. Funcionou ao usar o `Filter :=  NOT (id IN ( 22 , 43 ) )`

Comment: Agora eu só não sei, posso responder e aceitar minha própria resposta para fechar a pergunta?

Comment: @Diego_F pode sim, inclusive essa resposta, em minha opinião, seria melhor como um comentário.

Comment: @Melissa Só posso aceitar a resposta daqui a 2 dias, mas esta feito. Obrigado.